# Trying to connect a Python program to Sharepoint REST API using Client ID

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint, clientid

I am having a problem connecting my Python program to my company's **Sharepoint** using REST APIs.

I tried using Shaperpoint API queries using **ClientContext** class but I get this error:
`Cannot get binary security token for from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf`, that I can't seem to understand.
Can someone tell me how to connect my program propperly?
Thank you!

Here's a link to the image: [Error while connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Lcm.png)

Comment: same issue here. Any updates?